# How to reload a page in a specific div, after a conditional else statement

Tags: php, jquery, html, reload

That's my first post, hope there're no mistakes!

I have an index.html page with divs and stuff and inside a div named "central" my code load different pages selected by button click functions. One of those "page into page" have a jQuery.post call to a php script that passes values to a JS function. Everything works fine but that's where my problem starts:
how can I reload into "central" page the same page to reinitialize the php script? I tried another jQUery.load() call and a location.reload() function but both seems to not work (well actually they reload the whole page, not only the central div).

I really appreciate any kind of suggestions, thanks =)

that's my code, at the end of random.js there's an else statement, i think there should go the reload function

**random.html**

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div id="random" class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="row">   
            <div>
                <h3 style="text-align:center;">
                    Domanda n° <span id="divNumero">
                    </span>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">   
            <div>
                <span id="divDomanda" style="margin: 15px 0 15px 0;">
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <h2>
                    <span id="divRispostaCifrata">
                    </span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rispostaInsert">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="check" type="button">
                        Check!
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="alert alert-default" id="helpRisposta" role="alert">
                La risposta è lunga <span id="divLung"></span> lettere
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div id="alertDiv" class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="alert" class="col-lg-12">        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(initRandom());
</script>
```

**random.php**

```
<?php
include_once "function.php";

$array_DB=retrieveDB();
$controllo=true;
do{
    $i=mt_rand(0,(count($array_DB)-1));
    if($array_DB[$i]['visibile']!=0)
        $controllo=false;
}
while($controllo);

$indice=$array_DB[$i]['indice'];
$domanda=$array_DB[$i]['domanda'];
$risposta=$array_DB[$i]['risposta'];
$rispostaCrypt=convert();
$lung=strlen($risposta);
echo json_encode(array(
                        'indice'=>$indice,
                        'domanda'=>$domanda,
                        'risposta'=>$risposta,
                        'rispostaCrypt'=>$rispostaCrypt,
                        'lung'=>$lung
                        )
                );



function convert(){
global $risposta;
$temp='';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($risposta);$i++)
{
    if($risposta[$i]==(' '))
        $temp.=' ';

    else if($risposta[$i]==('-'))
        $temp.='-';

    else
        $temp.='#';
}
return $temp;
}
?>
```

**random.js**

```
function initRandom(){
jQuery.post("pages/random.php",(function(sendback){

    var indice=0;
    var domanda;
    var risposta;
    var lung;
    var rispostaCrypy;

    response=jQuery.parseJSON(sendback);

    indice=response.indice;
    domanda=response.domanda;
    risposta=response.risposta;
    lung=response.lung;
    rispostaCrypt=response.rispostaCrypt;

    jQuery("#divNumero").text(indice);
    jQuery("#divDomanda").text(domanda);
    jQuery("#divRispostaCifrata").text(rispostaCrypt);
    jQuery("#divLung").text(lung);

    controlla(indice,domanda,risposta)
}))

}

function controlla(indice,domanda,risposta){

var temp='';
jQuery("#check").click(function(){

        temp='';
        if(!(jQuery("#rispostaInsert").val())){
            alertDiv("Forse dovresti inserire una risposta");
        }
    else{
        var rispostaI=jQuery("#rispostaInsert").val()
        var lungRspInsert=rispostaI.length;
        var lungRsp=risposta.length;
        if((lungRspInsert)<(lungRsp)){
            var diff=lungRsp - lungRspInsert;
        alertDiv("Mancano "+diff+" lettere")
        }
        else if((lungRspInsert)>(lungRsp)){
            var diff=lungRspInsert - lungRsp;
            alertDiv("Ci sono "+diff+" lettere in più");
        }
        else if((lungRspInsert)==(lungRsp)){

            var contatore=0;
            for(var i=0;i<lungRsp;i++)
            {
                if(rispostaI.charAt(i).toLowerCase()==risposta.charAt(i).toLowerCase()){
                    temp+=risposta.charAt(i)
                    contatore++;    
                }
                else{
                    temp+='#';
                }
            }
            jQuery("#divRispostaCifrata").text("").text(temp);
            if(contatore!=lungRsp){
                jQuery("#helpRisposta").text("").text("Indovinate "+contatore+" lettere su "+lungRsp)
            }
            else{
                alertDiv("COMPLIMENTI! La risposta è corretta");

            }
        }

    }
});

}
```

Comment: What exactly you wanne reload? The code between the `random` div?

Comment: You can call this function `initRandom()` again in the click event.

Comment: There's a lack of explanation in my post, i'll try to explain better:

Comment: I've a button id="random" that start the initRandom() function that calls a php file and excecute the controlla() function on the page. (it's a sort of hanged game) when the user insert the right answer function controlla() print the success alert and, obviously, stop. If i click again on the random button the script starts again (and it works very well). What i would like to achieve is to reload the initRandom() function when the controlla() function ends (reload when the answer's correct without press again the random butn

Comment: I solved by myself. There was a stupid error in the div class in jQuery. Thanks to all of you =)